# How to view the history of the command "passwd <username>"

Tags: linux, security, password, audit

I'am looking for a way to audit the history of password change for the user `root` (the `passwd` command) for a local network server.

How i can view the date and/or the time of execution this command and by IP address?

Answer (score 5):

You can't tell who issued a `passwd` and from where.

But my Ubuntu is configured to log password changes to `/var/log/auth.log` and my RHEL and CentOS log password changes to `/var/log/secure`, *if* they are made with the passwd command. You will see `pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for` messages.

So unless somebody modified /etc/shadow directly (possible for an admin) you can see **when** a  password was set.

When the *current* password was set is also stored in /etc/shadow

See https://linux.die.net/man/3/shadow and https://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow

The  third field in the file containing the password hashes `/etc/shadow`  is `sp_lstchg` - the number of days since Jan 1, 1970 when the password was last changed.

```
root@serverfault:~# grep root /etc/shadow
root:*:17928:0:99999:7:::
       ^^^^^

root@serverfault:~# date --date '1970-01-01 +17928days'
Fri Feb  1 00:00:00 CET 2019
```